# Equation number alignment error

Tags: equations, numbering

This equation number is in chapter 3, so when it comes like 3.45 in front of the equation, then no space with the equation and the equation number

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    A_{1}r^{-(g_{0}(z)+g_{1}(z,\lambda))/B} \bigg(\frac{d g_{0}}{g z} +\frac{g g_{1}}{g z}\bigg) + (B_{2}+C_{c})r^{-(c_{0}(z)+c_{1}(z,\lambda)+f_{2}(z))/k}\bigg(\frac{d f_{0}}{d y} +\frac{d f_{1}}{d z}+\frac{d f_{x}}{d z}\bigg)-ccf=0 \nonumber  \\
 (1+ggr^{f_{2}(b)/rr}) \bigg(\frac{d f_{gg}}{d z} +\frac{d f_{1}}{dhh}\bigg) +\frac{d f_{2}}{d z}-ff=0 \label{mmm6}
     \end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop using `eqnarray` use `align` from `amsmath`. AMS tracks the width of the equation number and move it out of the way if necessary, `eqnarray` obviously does not.

For more info as to why one should not use `eqnarray` see:

http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html

Comment: but then equation number goes to a new row

Comment: Where else should it go?

Comment: cant we get the equation number on the same line where the equation is?

Comment: If the EQ is too long, then how? Breaking display eqs are extremely difficult business, just look at the breqn package which is an attempt to solve this. So for most people it is better to break these eqs by hand. That is also what I do all the time. It other ends up being easier to understand for the reader