# The equation number doesn't appear

Tags: equations

I was trying to create an aligned numbering of equations, but I don't know if I am using the right order, the equation numner does not appear:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry}

%\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
%\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
%\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
\label{10}

\begin{aligned}

\begin{center}


\[
  ABD =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      126102075.631 &   56957543.627 &     0    &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
      56957543.627 &  107378189.106 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\ 
             0   &         0   &  28004682.576 &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  373.068  &  1250.853 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  1250.853 &    2.404 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &    0    &    0    &  1.22
    \end{bmatrix}
\]




\end{center}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: get rid of the `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` and `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.  they aren't doing anything.  then replace `\[` and `\]` by `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` respectively.  the code with brackets says "this is an unnumbered display equation".  also, you should never have blank lines within the scope of a multi-line display.

Comment: thank you dear Barbara , well I did it , but now I can not number it at all!!! in this way the equation can not be numbered @barbarabeeton

Comment: @barbarabeeton in this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138800/equation-number-alignment-error it is advised to stop using eqnarray and use align, so I dont know now, what to do..

Comment: that is not your problem.  your problem is that the matrix is wider than the text area on the page.  see the answers that have been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're trying too hard.  all you need is the single wrapper
`\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{10}
  ABD =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      126102075.631 &   56957543.627 &     0    &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
      56957543.627 &  107378189.106 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\ 
             0   &         0   &  28004682.576 &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  373.068  &  1250.853 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  1250.853 &    2.404 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &    0    &    0    &  1.22
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And here is a reference to the equation \eqref{10}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the problem here is that the matrix is too wide for the page, and the equation number
is appearing *under* the right-hand side of the equation, at the normal margin.

if you decrease the font size, wrapping it in this "container"

```
{\footnotesize
 ...
}
```

you will get this result:

[image: output of enhanced wxample code]

as you can see, it is still very wide -- still too wide for the equation number to
fit beside it -- but it's more obvious that there is an equation number.

i'm not sure what to suggest to make this fit better; decreasing the type size
indefinitely is not an improvement.  and the gap between columns is already quite
small relative to the contents.

Comment: I used it in another equation , but now the numbering went to the other side of the formula , I mean to left of the page instead of right, despite that there is enough space on the right corner @barbarabeeton

Comment: it shouldn't do that if it's in the same file as the equation in the example here.  without a lot of effort, equation numbers don't switch sides.  have you done something like specify `[leqno]` in the options to the document class?  i think another example is needed, hence another question.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one equation, you should use the `equation` environment alone for this.

In the following code I've got rid of all the commands, packages and options which are not needed for your example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  ABD =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      126102075.631 &   56957543.627 &     0    &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
      56957543.627 &  107378189.106 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\ 
             0   &         0   &  28004682.576 &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  373.068  &  1250.853 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  1250.853 &    2.404 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &    0    &    0    &  1.22
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You can see that a number is given to your equation then (here (1)).
[image]