# the equation number jumps to the left of the page

Tags: equations

I wrote a code and I wonder following the regular order , the number jumps to the left of the page

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\hyphenation{a-gen-tiz-za-zio-ne}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm]{geometry}

%\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
%\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
%\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{1} 

$(SF1, SF2, SF3, SF4, SF5) =  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z0} (\sigma11,\sigma22,\sigma12,\sigma13,\sigma23)dz$



$(SM1, SM2, SM3) =  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z0}(\sigma11,\sigma22,\sigma12)zdz$


\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh dear... you shouldn't use empty/blank lines inside `equation`, *nor* force math mode `$`...`$`, since you're already in math mode.

Comment: I can't see how this would compile as-is, let alone make "the equation number _jump_ to the left."

Comment: That blank lines are not allowed within math equations was already mentioned by me in [unusual distance between the paragraphs ,how to fix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235236)

Comment: Looking at [LateX is unnecessarily centring all of my text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233436) which seems to be the topic in several of your question, the questions themselves as well as the asnwers, which almost always are pure guesswork, i wish you to do one thing: Read a proper introduction. That will be time well invested and you can figure out stuff like that within one minute yourself in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the kind of construction, where only one equation number is wanted for a
multi-line expression, that is best input using the `equation` environment with a
"subsidiary" environment nested inside of it.

i suggest this input code:

```
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\begin{aligned}
(SF1, SF2, SF3, SF4, SF5) & =  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z0} (\sigma11,\sigma22,\sigma12,\sigma13,\sigma23)dz\\
(SM1, SM2, SM3) & =  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z0}(\sigma11,\sigma22,\sigma12)zdz
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

(i am not repeating the entire code, since this is essentially the same as what was
used in [your earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235986/579). thank you,
though, for posing this as a new question.)

here is the output:

[image: output of example code]

as you can see, the equation number is on the right-hand, not the left-hand side.

as various commenters have pointed out, you should *not* (not ever!) have blank lines
within the scope of the `equation` environment (or, indeed, within any math environment).
and once you are in math mode, don't use `$` signs; they only confuse things.

you would get some benefit from reading the `amsmath` documentation -- `texdoc amsmath`.

Answer (score 2):

After removing the syntax errors (`$` inside displayed math, `\par`/empty lines inside environment `equation`) and some guesses (two equations, maybe aligned at the equals sign, subscripts, ...):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{1}
(SF1, SF2, SF3, SF4, SF5) &=  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z_0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z_0}
(\sigma_{11},\sigma_{22},\sigma_{12},\sigma_{13},\sigma_{23})\diff z
\\
(SM1, SM2, SM3) &=  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z_0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z_0}
(\sigma_{11},\sigma_{22},\sigma_{12})z \diff z
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

I am not sure about the meaning of `SF1` to `SF5` and `SM1` to `SM3`. Therefore I left them unchanged.

Maybe they are some program variables, then they could be set as:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\newcommand*{\var}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{1}
(\var{SF1}, \var{SF2}, \var{SF3}, \var{SF4}, \var{SF5}) &=  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} -
(\sigma_{11},\sigma_{22},\sigma_{12},\sigma_{13},\sigma_{23})\diff z
\\
(\var{SM1}, \var{SM2}, \var{SM3}) &=  \int_{-\frac{h}{2} - z_0}^{\frac{h}{2} - z_
(\sigma_{11},\sigma_{22},\sigma_{12})z \diff z
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]